# If publishes faster than calling SpinOnce, would CallBack Queue be filled up eventually?

Tags: ros, spinonce, callbackqueue

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If we have a publisher publishing at 40Hz, and the subscriber is calling SpinOnce at 20Hz, would our CallBack Queue be filled up eventually?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46535/if-publishes-faster-than-calling-spinonce,-would-callback-queue-be-filled-up-eventually?/) by [Dumpsomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/3304/dumpsomer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2012-10-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Depends on how long your callbacks run. But spinOnce does not just execute only one callback but it will empty the queue if possible and then return.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4